# What is reason for datavaluefield when we have datatext field in ASP.NET dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

1. What is reason for datavaluefield when we have datatext field in ASP.NET dropdownlist?
2. What is reason for ddl.selectedvalue and ddl.selecteditem.text when we can do ddl.text?

Answer (score 1):

They are **not** the same thing. The tooling (VS) may make you *think* it is because of its default behavior. `text` is display, `value` is value. At the end of the day, this is what it means:

Control

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
   <asp:ListItem Value="datavaluefield1">datatext 1</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="datavaluefield2">datatext 2</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="datavaluefield3">datatext 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Rendered HTML:

```
<select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1">
   <option value="datavaluefield1">datatext 1</option> 
   <option value="datavaluefield2">datatext 2</option>
   <option value="datavaluefield3">datatext 3</option>
</select>
```

Same idea for *selected* depending on what you are after (value vs text).

**If** you used the same piece of data for `value` and `text`, then yeah, you can use either.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="foo">foo</asp:ListItem>
```

renders:

```
<select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1">
   <option value="foo">foo</option>
```

---

Additionally, outside of ASP.Net, let's say you need to POST to some other resource, it will be the `value` that is sent.

```
//input_name_key=input_name_selected_value
DropDownList1=the_selected_value
```

So in the above example, if you selected the 3rd item:

```
DropDownList1=datavaluefield3 //not "datatext 3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon EdSF's explanation of the difference, and to give a real world example, say you have a database table of STATES:

```
STATE_ID    STATE_NAME
----------------------
1           Michigan
2           Colorado
3           Florida
```

With this kind of data, you could use the DataValueField to hold the STATE_ID and the DataTextField to hold the STATE_NAME. The name of the state would then be what gets displayed as the text to choose from and the ID would be a value tied to the name behind the scenes.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
    DataValueField="STATE_ID"
    DataTextField="STATE_NAME">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Say you are then storing addresses in another table and that table holds a foreign key to your STATES table. Passing the ID of the state to the stored procedure is much simpler than doing another sub-query on the state's name (a name that could potentially be updated at any time and therefore not exist as you once knew).

```
int stateID = int.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
```

So just as EdSF mentioned, they are not the same and can be used to hold different values if you so choose.